# Scala set SBT breakpoint without Intellij

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to migrate off Intellij (it keeps breaking, losing configuration options and generally being more painful to use than a text editor and a net productivity loss for myself). In C you can use GDB to specify a file and line for a breakpoint to stop on. Is there a way to do something similar in SBT or other Scala tools?

Comment: Please do report issues on how IntelliJ-Scala breaks or is painful for you, we are always trying to improve it :)

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's just problems being a beginner with newer software. If I get better repro steps I'll report it. I had a .idea project that had .idea projects within it and they weren't picking up JVM or scala library settings properly.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [JDB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) in Java world, which is similar to GDB. Since, Scala at the end uses JVM, jdb should work fine for Scala code as well. There is no much of a specific integration in sbt for jdb, but all you need to do is to run your JVM properly with something similar to:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,address=jdbconn,server=y,suspend=n
```

(which could be specified in the sbt build file), and later you need to connect with jdb with this:

```
jdb -attach jdbconn
```

Jdb supports all basic command line debugging commands like print, run, stop at, etc.

Comment: Cool - I'm assuming I'd have to use this on the class files resulting from compilation or would it work on just the scala files as well? The JVM stack isn't necessarily my forte.

Comment: Yes, you could use jdb on resulting class files as well, but I think it will be complex for a full debug purposes, running jvm container and be able to debug it via jdb is much more convenient to me

Answer (score 1):

You can give [Scala debugger](https://scala-debugger.org/) project a try.

It's got standard debugger features:

- Running a program step-by-step
- Breaking a program to examine its state
- Watching variables in a program
- Evaluating expressions